# How can non-admin users connect to Wi-Fi networks?

Tags: xubuntu, network-manager, policykit

I'm trying to configure PolicyKit so that other users are allowed to configure Wi-Fi connections, but my changes don't seem to bring any results at all.

When a non-admin user tries to connect to a new Wi-Fi, I get the **System policy prevents modification of network settings for all users** box. It asks for the admin user's password.

Ok - that one goes via PolicyKit, so I thought I'll just change the configuration for action `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system`. I created a file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/52-wifi-management.conf` with content:

```
[Wifi management]
Identity=unix-group:netdev
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

and added the user to the `netdev` group.

But that didn't make any difference. There also doesn't seem to be much possibility for debugging the auth process. What's going wrong? How do I make it work as I expect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove sudo password when connecting to \*new\* WiFi network](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244567/remove-sudo-password-when-connecting-to-new-wifi-network)

Comment: There's a working solution on [another question](http://askubuntu.com/a/315900/28930)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration is correct, but local policy files should be placed inside `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/` and the file extension must be `.pkla`.

To solve your problem:

```
sudo mv /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/52-wifi-management.conf /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/52-wifi-management.pkla
```

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu-desktop-privileges packages should already contain a policy that allows console users to configure network devices. Is that package not installed on your system?

Comment: Actually the package is named "policykit-desktop-privileges". From the package description: _It does not change privileges for non-Administrators (users who are not in the "admin" or "sudo" group)_.