# How do I reconnect my WiFi without entering the superuser password?

Tags: networking, wireless, password, vnc, mythbuntu

The connection to my Mythbuntu system was recently changed from cable to WiFi. Now sometimes the computer disconnects the WiFi-connection and prompts for authentication.

How do I tell Mythbuntu to automatically reconnect if the WiFi is disconnected? The computer is only accessible over VNC. If the WiFi connection drops, the computer has to be connected by cable, I have to login, enter the password, and disconnect. Also, can I find out why the window comes up in the first place?

The window asking for a password looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4JpZ.jpg

Comment: Check the directory `/etc/NetworkManager` for ownership and permissions. The directory itself should be `drwxr-xr-x` and so should the directory `system-connections` under it. Everything should be owned by root.

Comment: Speaking of system-connections, there should be a file which lists settings for the network. Make a copy of that file, if you can, delete original, place the copy back in. Also try doing `sudo service network-manager restart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. First I tried the suggestions in the comments to no avail. After a bit of searching of "Die Systemrichtlinien verhindern das Bearbeiten von Netzwerkeinstellungen für alle Benutzer" I found a Launchpad entry connected to this problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1045972

I created a file `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/wifi.pkla` with the content:

```
[Changing system-wide NetworkManager connections]
Identity=unix-user:-the-user-
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system
ResultActive=yes
```

This solution is very close to the one found at [How can non-admin users connect to Wi-Fi networks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230825/how-can-non-admin-users-connect-to-wi-fi-networks)

Worked instantly without rebooting.