# Is this a security backdoor?

Tags: sudo, security, nmcli

I just realised nmcli commands don't ask me password for sudo access, but ends up modifying a file under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ which is root-only access.

How is this allowed? What's the mechanism that makes a process change a file that the user doesn't have access to?

Details are, I've got a vpn connection, let's say my-vpn, and run for example:

```
nmcli c modify my-vpn +ipv4.dns 192.168.1.12
```

and the /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my-vpn file is modified to include the dns.

Comment: The authentication mechanism is likely [PolicyKit](https://wiki.debian.org/PolicyKit). See for example [How can non-admin users connect to Wi-Fi networks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230825/how-can-non-admin-users-connect-to-wi-fi-networks). Members of `unix-group:sudo` group are given `localauthority` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not.

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges#Use_Network_Manager

> All users at the console can manage Ethernet, wireless and 3G networks using Network Manager via DBus. (Ref.: /etc/dbus-1/system.d/NetworkManager.conf, /etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-applet.conf)